# How do I code a simple integer circular buffer in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, circular-buffer

I see a lot of templates and complicated data structures for implementing a circular buffer.

How do I code a simple integer circular buffer for 5 numbers?

I'm thinking in C is the most straightforward?

Thanks.

Comment: The complexity of the code goes up with how safe and robust you want it to be.  Do you want it to prevent underflow/overflow, for instance?

Comment: Note:  a circular (ring) buffer is different than a circular *queue*.

Comment: I just need to store the 5 last values of some data, so whatever has a better design to do that.

Comment: @T.T.T. Do you need to retrieve them in a special order (FIFO, LIFO, no ordering) ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have an array, `buffer`, of 5 integers.  Have an index `ind` to the next element.  When you add, do

```
buffer[ind] = value;
ind = (ind + 1) % 5;
```

Comment: From the personal experience file, you need to be careful that ind is not negative.  If you change the second line to "ind = (max(0,ind) % 1) + 5;", you don't have to worry about negative values for ind.

Comment: Why don't you just set ind to be uint? That would solve your problem more efficiently if only additions are involved

Answer (score 12):

Take an array, `arr`, an index `idx`, and a counter, `num`.

To insert `foo`, say `arr[idx++] = foo; idx %= buffer_len; num++;`.

To read out an item into `foo`, say `foo = arr[(idx-num)%buffer_len]; num--;`.

Add boundary checks.

Comment: You don't need num and idx.

Answer (score 1):

If the size and data type of your buffer are fixed, a simple array is all you need:

```
 int buffer[5];
```

Add to that a couple pointers:

```
 int* start = &buffer[0];
 int* end   = &buffer[4]+1;
 int* input = start;
 int* output = start;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int rI =0;
int wI=0;
#define FIFO_SIZE 3
int checkAvail()
{
int avail=0;

if(wI<rI)
    avail= (rI-wI);
else
    avail = (FIFO_SIZE-wI+rI);
return avail;
}

int addFIFO(int *a, int val)
{
if(checkAvail()>0)
{
    a[wI]=val;
    wI++;
    if(wI>FIFO_SIZE)
        wI=0;
}
else
{
    printf("FIFO full");
}
return 0;
}
 int remFIFO(int *a)
 {
 int val;
if((FIFO_SIZE-checkAvail()>0))
{
    val =a[rI];
    rI++;
    if(rI>FIFO_SIZE)
        rI=0;
}
else
{
    printf("FIFO empty");
}
return 0;
}
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
int FIFO_ARRAY[FIFO_SIZE]={};
addFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY,1);
addFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY,2);
addFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY,3);
addFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY,4);
remFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY);
remFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY);
remFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY);
remFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY);
remFIFO(FIFO_ARRAY);
}
```