# How can I have a compile-time const object configured with a chunk of data of variable length?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Currently I'm struggling with something like this:

```
class Command final {
    const std::vector<uint8_t> cmd;
public:
    constexpr Command(const std::initializer_list<uint8_t> cmd_)
        :cmd(cmd_)
        {}
    void copyToWithSlightModifications(uint8_t* buf, size_t len) { /*...*/ }
    std::string getSomeInformation() { /*...*/ }
}

const Command cmd1({ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 });
const Command cmd2({ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 });
// lots more of these
```

Of course, `std::vector` is not something that works here, but it's here as it expresses my intent best. I tried `std::array` and a few other ideas, but also have failed.

Background: this is for embedded development, so I'm tight on resources and consting things tends to put them to flash where memory is cheap. Doing it as a real vector will put this into scarce RAM memory. This is on gcc version 5.2.0.

TL;DR: I need to have a variable length container that I can put as a field on a const object with and initialize it in constexpr context. Any idea what that might look like? Doesn't have to be anything fancy, if it's a `uint8_t*` and a `size_t` with it's size, that will work too.

Comment: This actually looks like you only need to store several arrays of variable size at compile time and then use array view for `Command` construction.

Comment: @VTT: yours is a proper solution but I was searching for something a bit more easily containable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of your description and the code snippet, this seems to fit the criteria.

```
template<size_t N>
class Command
{
    uint8_t cmd[N];
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr Command(Args... args) : cmd{uint8_t(args)...}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == N,
                      "argument count mismatch");
    }
};

constexpr Command<4> cmd4{0, 1, 2, 3};
constexpr Command<2> cmd2{0, 1};
```

You may also write a helper function to avoid explicitly typing the argument count

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr Command<sizeof...(Args)> make_command(Args... args)
{
    return {args...};
}

constexpr auto cmd4 = make_command(0, 1, 2, 3);
constexpr auto cmd2 = make_command(0, 1);
```

Alternatively, in C++17 there is template deduction guides

```
template<typename... Args>
Command(Args...) -> Command<sizeof...(Args)>;

constexpr Command cmd4{0, 1, 2, 3};
constexpr Command cmd2{0, 1};
```

Note however, a different sized `Command` is a different type, meaning they won't fit in a container.

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to use your solution with slight modification and introduction of a base interface class. For anyone interested here's a minimal example: https://ideone.com/Mg32QW

Comment: One more thing - my compiler has one issue with this answer, namely I can do `Command c1{ uint8_t{1}, uint8_t{2} }` but not `Command c2{0x01, 0x02}` because of `narrowing conversion of 'args#...' from 'int' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' inside { }` - any ideas on this one, @Passer By?

Comment: For the pre-C++17 case, you can add a point of deduction: `auto make_command(Args&&... args) -> Command<sizeof...(Args)> { return Command<sizeof...(Args)>(std::forward<Args...>(args...); }`

Comment: @KrzysztofBociurko The literals are deduced to have type `int`, and due to the limitations of the compilers warnings, it will still warn you of narrowing conversions even when it is known at compile time the values won't overflow.

Comment: @Caleth Yes of course, dunno why I didn't think of it. Thanks.

Comment: @KrzysztofBociurko I added in an explicit cast to remedy that.

Comment: @PasserBy my compiler required adding a `constexpr` to `make_command`, but apart from this small issue, this is exactly what was needed, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In deeply embedded you usually use circular buffers so solve this kind of problem.
They have a fixed maximal size but depending on implementation they behave just like lists.
Unfortunately the standard c++ library does not have any circular buffers but there are plenty of tutorials on the web.

I doublt you can use boost library on your restricted system but in case you do you can simply use [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

Some other pages that might help you implement an circular buffer suitable for you might be [this](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/4/6/circular-buffers-in-cc) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621956/how-do-i-code-a-simple-integer-circular-buffer-in-c-c)

Comment: Don't understand why a circular buffer might of use here. Circular buffers are for FIFOs and such where data ordered is constantly moving - and this ought to be a storage class that is not changing at any time.

Could you clarify?

Comment: You can perform random access on elements of a ring buffer. You may give them a large enough fixed size and use it as if it were dynamic.

Comment: So you mean using a circular buffer as a non-circular plain old static array with pointers to specific places in it? Or is there any hidden benefit of it's added complexity?

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, there will be an issue with properly initiating it. All will have to be done by hand, including counting the offsets of separate commands.

Comment: It seems i misunderstood your question. I got it that you want a data structure with a variable count of elements but statically initialized. If this isn't what your question was about i'm gonna delete this answer.